# Prevent duplicates in a SP list. I am using Javascript

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, javascript

I am trying to prevent duplicates in a SP list but my code does not work.
e.g if an item "James" exists in my list it should not be possible to add same item instead an alert message should show up "Item already exists". but if item "James" does not exist than it should be added.

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var parrentConetxt = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebUrl);
    var parrentWeb = parrentConetxt.get_web();
    var list = parrentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("testList");
    var items = list.getItems("");
    var createItem = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = list.addItem(createItem);

    function add() {
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onS);

}

    function onS() {
    var Enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

    while (Enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = Enumerator.get_current();
        if (currentItem.get_item("Title") = $("#txtTitle").val()) 
        {
            alert("Item alredy exists");
        }
        else {
            newItem.set_item("Title", $("#txtTitle").val());
            newItem.update();
        }
        clientContext.load(list);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onF);
    }
}

    function onF() {
    alert("Error");
}
```

Comment: Why not just enable the unique option on the field settings? Then simply try to add your item, you should get the error message in the callback. Let SharePoint work for you.

Comment: Ok I'll try it.thx!

Comment: Use enforce unique values, under list settings instead of writing code. Go to List Settings ---> Click on Column you want the unique names and then set the parameter enforce unique values to YES.

Comment: I did, works fine now. thx!

Comment: And on another note, you should use CAML query, instead of iterating all the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists columns have this functionality built in. Simply enable the enforce unique values option on your desired column.

Then you try to add your item like normal in your JavaScript code. Any error you will receive in the callback and you can handle however you'd like at that point.

Let the built in SharePoint functionality work for you.